# iwlist scan return no result (ra0)

Tags: wifi, raspbian

I'm trying to run the following command `iwlist ra0 scan` (ra0 = WLAN 5GHz) and I get as output:

> ra0       No scan results

There is my configuration:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iwconfig
      ra0       Ralink STA  ESSID:""  Nickname:"MT7610U_STA"
                Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
                Bit Rate:1 Mb/s
                RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
                Link Quality=10/100  Signal level:0 dBm  Noise level:0 dBm
                Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
                Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
      ra0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 01:23:45:67:89:ab
                inet addr:169.254.185.103  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
                inet6 addr: fe80::f6dd:c143:6e27:d133/64 Scope:Link
                UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
                RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

pi@raspberrypi:~ $  uname -a
      Linux raspberrypi 4.4.34-v7+ #930 SMP Wed Nov 23 15:20:41 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Does someone know how to manage to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I see your ra0 wireless interface has Mode as "Auto". You can change mode to Managed and then try "iwlist ra0 s".

*Command to change mode: iwconfig ra0 mode Managed*

**FYI: Managed means Station mode, Master means AP mode.**

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. I found a way to make it work installing _network-manager_ but I would like to run it **manually**, without any extension.